# How to read excel one cell date(DD/MM/YYYY) value and convert date format into (M/D/YYYY) using PHPExcel library

Tags: php, excel, csv, phpexcel, date-formatting

I'm converting excel file data into csv file using php PHPExcel library. currently i'm getting all data from excel into csv. but i need to change date format in one particular cell [ex. B2]
in excel its date(**DD/MM/YYYY**) i want to change it as **M/D/YYYY** and same it to csv.

Note: I'm using **phpexcel library** to read excel fi

i tried the following code:

```php
<?php
$excel_lib = '/var/www/mp/cronfiles/data/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
include($excel_lib);
$filearray = array('file1.xlsx','file2.csv','file3.csv');
$file2 = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$filearray[0],"r");
if (!$file2) {
                echo "File not exisit";
            }
$inputFileType1 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filearray[0]);
$objReader1 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType1);
$objPHPExcel1 = $objReader1->load($filearray[0]);
$sheet1 = $objPHPExcel1->getSheet(0);

      $highestRow1 = $sheet1->getHighestRow();

      $highestColumn1 = $sheet1->getHighestColumn();

      $rowData1 = array();

  for ($row1 = 1; $row1 <= $highestRow1; $row1++) { 
    $rowData1[] = $sheet1->rangeToArray('A' . $row1 . ':' . $highestColumn1 . $row1, null, true, true);
  }

  foreach($rowData1 AS $k => $v){
      foreach ($v AS $fk => $fv){
          $csv[] = $fv;
          }
      }

$excel_date = 'As of '.$csv[1][1]; //its B2 cell in excel value ex.[echo $excel_date; output 22/6/2019]
$changed_date = date_format('M/d/Y', $excel_date);
echo $change_date;
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given in var/www/html/mp/cronfiles/data/myfile.php**

**My question**:
1. How to get excel cell value in date format so i can convert it.

**Note**: In excel the B2 cell value that i'm trying to get is in date format only. but its changing depend on my excel default language.

Please let me know if you need more information. I hope i'll get fix here.

Thanks in advance.

By
Agan

Comment: can give picture of your excel one row showing date column.

Comment: For excel screenshot please check the link (https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4414297/9cfc23c31b2e0d0278043c9b8afcc624)

Answer (score 1):

You are received date format in excel date format. First you have to convert to php datetime format then convert to desire output format.

Use this code :

```php
$excel_date = $csv[1][1];  //22/6/2019;   
$changed_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $excel_date)->format('D/M/Y');
echo $changed_date;
```

for your requirement to decide which format is excel date is given use below code :

```php
function convert_date_format($old_date = '')     {  
 $old_date = trim($old_date);        
    if (preg_match('/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9])\/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/[0-9]{4}$/', $old_date)) // MySQL-compatible YYYY-MM-DD format  
     {   return 'm/d/Y';     }   
     elseif (preg_match('/^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9])\/[0-9]{4}$/', $old_date)) // DD-MM-YYYY format  
     {   return 'd/m/Y';
     }    
 }

$excel_format = convert_date_format($excel_date);
$changed_date = DateTime::createFromFormat($excel_format, $excel_date)->format('D/M/Y');
echo $changed_date;
```

Comment: PHP considers / to mean m/d/Y and - to mean d-m-Y.(in excel i'm getting both type date value in same cell like m/d/Y sometime d/m/Y : excel file changed every day) issue is i need to find value in excel is in m/d/YYYY or d/m/YYYY. without knowing this its hard to get output what i want. can you help me on this?

Comment: try this am getting output for this $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '22/6/2019')->format('D/M/Y'); is Sat/Jun/2019

Comment: Sometime i get excel value in d/m/Y format (22/6/2019) sometime m/d/y format(6/22/2019). this is what make this hard.
how to find what format currently its in excel without knowing this its not possible to get output. no matter what format in excel i get output in m/d/Y format only.

Comment: @aviboy2066
It's working only date limit from (13/9/2019 to 30/9/2019)[DD/MM/YYYY]. if i gave date below 13th like 12/9/2019[DD/MM/YYYY] its miscalculate and says 12/9/2019 as MM/DD/YYYY format. but its wrong.

Comment: its working for me. for any date there is no year or month specific. I changed code to handle 1-9 month without trailing 0